# RegRead Function returns a wrong value

Tags: vbscript

I have a script to read registry values. It worked till now but this time it gives me a wrong result

Here's the actual registry value along with the value returned by the code below:

[image: Registry value]

And here's the code I'm using:

```
FileExt = "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{F02C1A0D-BE21-4350-88B0- 
7367FC96EF3C}\ShellFolder\Attributes"
Set Shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
St = Shell.RegRead(FileExt)
wscript.echo St
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value in the registry is a 32-bit *unsigned* integer, but VBScript interprets it as a 32-bit *signed* integer (see for instance [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2004/12/03/integer-arithmetic-in-vbscript-part-two/)).

Either display the hexadecimal value:

```
WScript.Echo Hex(St)
```

or adjust the misinterpreted value:

```
If St < 0 Then St = St + 2^32
WScript.Echo St
```